# problems with decrementing decimals in react

Tags: reactjs, input, decimal, decrement

the problem is simple but i don't understand why it happens, when i create a variable with decimals, for example 3.544 and then i create a increment and decrement buttons just for increment by 1 and decrement by 1, when it reach 1.544 it happens: (I created a new react project but this happen in my work proyect too.

this is the image of what happens:

[image: this is the image of what happens]

```
`
 import logo from './logo.svg';
 function App() {

   let number = 3.455

   return (
     <div className="App">
     <header className="App-header">
     <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
     <p>
       Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
     </p>

     <button onClick={()=>{
       number=number+1
       console.log(number)
    }}>
     +
    </button>
    <button onClick={()=>{
      number=number-1
      console.log(number)
    }}>
      -
    </button>

  </header>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

I debugged and i found the problem is in react-dom file after excecuting the onClick method of the button, the value goes to 0.4550000000... in there

Comment: These are not decimals

Comment: What do you mean?, im decrementing 3.455 in this example and for any reason when i reach 0, it console log this 0.45500000000007

Comment: I mean javascript numbers are not decimals but 64-bit floats. Thus, what you have is a float arithmetics which doesn't produce exact values. You either use `.toFixed` to format values in a specific way or use a dedicated library for decimal processin, e.g. [bignumbers.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)